# Various types of Notification Centers available for iOS

Tags: ios, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I'm currently working on notification centers.

I read that there are 4 types of Notification Centers are there.

1. **NSNotificationCenter**
2. **NSDistributedNotificationCenter**
3. **DarwinNotificationCenter**
4. **TelephonyNotificationCenter**

In which `NSNotificationCenter` I'm familiar with. `TelephonyNotificationCenter` is private and not provided for developers.

My question is about `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` and `DarwinNotificationCenter`.

What is the use of these two notification centers ? Is it available for developers ? If available how can I use them ?

**What I tried:**

1. Googled, got two reference ([DarwinNotificationConcepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/MacOSXNotifcationOv/DarwinNotificationConcepts/DarwinNotificationConcepts.html) , [NSDistributedNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDistributedNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)). But confused after reading.
2. Read the iOS books available on this [link](http://www.informit.com/authors/bio.aspx?a=8FF32343-952D-4C6F-BFA6-F4B757655420), get a overview. But nothing in details

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are aware that `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` and `DarwinNotificationCenter` are not available in iOS (a least not to Apples documentation)

Comment: @rckoenes: No, i was not aware. thanks for the information :)

Comment: for DarwinNotificationCenter under ios see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229955/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-ios-device-is-locked-unlocked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both DarwinNotificationConcepts and `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` are OS X specific and are **not available under iOS**.

The **Darwin Notification Concepts article** refers to the Unix under pinnings of MacOS X. Darwin being the Unix subsystem. It's best used for IPC between an application and a daemon and relies on `notifyd` to work.

`NSDistributedNotificationCenter` has the same basic working as `NSNotificationCenter` but works between processes. Available since OS X 10.0

Comment: This post shows how to access the DarwinNotificationCenter in iOS