# How know if iOS device is sleeping in a background process

Tags: ios, background, state, sleep

I have a application running in background and I need to know if device is sleeping in order to start a sincronisation process, but I didn't find information about this.

Does anyone know if it is posible and how do it?

Thanks.

Comment: please tell us more about what you are doing...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot know if the device is asleep because you have no control over the OS.

You can, otherwise, use the App Delegate method:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //your code goes here
}
```

if you want to wait till your app goes to background

Comment: This only shows whether this application become inactive. As example, it will do it when you exit to home screen (vs device falls asleep)

Comment: expecting the phone to "fall asleep" is not in the iOS practices. The iOS app should have control only over its own behavior, not the phone's

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't do this using public API. The only thing which you can check whether your application is active or in background (using AppDelegate callbacks). And as Luke pointed out in comments, checking whether device "falls asleep" isn't iOS best design practice.

There are some private API's to do what you want, you can look at following questions:

[Is there a way to check if the iOS device is locked/unlocked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229955/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-ios-device-is-locked-unlocked)

[Detect screen on/off from iOS service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191980/detect-screen-on-off-from-ios-service)

However, you should be aware that your app won't be accepted in AppStore in such case.