# Getting iOS daily device usage time and unlock count

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm fascinated by this app called Instant ([website](http://instantapp.today/) and [app store page](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id991690667?mt=8)) because it gathers device data that I thought was private:

- The day's **device usage time**, in minutes
- The **number of phone unlocks** that day

According to a post by one of the developers, they used a combination of APIs to find the data. I couldn't find further information on how they did this.

How do you access this information?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229955/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-ios-device-is-locked-unlocked