# ionic ios app rejected using com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I have an ios application created with ionic framework. But in my last submission app store has rejected my app and said,
Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs:

```
com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete
```

I was trying to find anything like in the above by searching through the project using xcode and visual studio code.
Can anyone give a suggestion to find the above command in the project/plugins? Any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39449334/can-i-use-com-apple-springboard-lockcomplete-notification Please check this

Comment: You cannot use this bundle identifier as it contains "com.apple". Go through this tutorial for more details - https://cocoacasts.com/what-are-app-ids-and-bundle-identifiers/

Comment: @PardeepBishnoi, this post is nothing to do with the app's bundle ID.