# Is there a way to find the iOS device lock status using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10-today-widget

I am working on newly enabled iOS 10 today-widgets on lock screen where I have show to user's information there. I want to hide it when the device is locked.

Is there any way to check the lock status programatically using Swift?

Comment: this question has  been asked a lot of times. Try to search. For example check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229955/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-ios-device-is-locked-unlocked

Comment: And if you want to convert Obj-c code to Swift. Go to this site https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/

Comment: I am looking if there is any solution in swift

Comment: I have commented a link for conversion as well, Conversion will not be 100% perfect but it will show you the way.