# Push notification sound disabled if phone locked, otherwise enabled

Tags: ios, swift

I want to have my push notifications play a sound when the iPhone is locked, but no sound when the iphone is unlocked.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, apple rejects applications with lock notifications listeners.

check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43624669/8192960).